# Minimum Iterations In Bisection Method

Tags: numerical-methods

I am using the Bisection Method to find a root for:

$$\frac{1.52}{(1+x)^2}-0.5\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{0.65x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

At $[0.1,2]$ and for $\varepsilon=0.01$

[Using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Analysis) $\log_2(\frac{b-a}{\varepsilon})\leq n$ I get that $7.56\leq n$

But applying the method I get $|f(1.7625)|\leq 0.01$ after just $3$ iterations

Is it due to a numerical issue with $\log_2(\frac{b-a}{\varepsilon})$ as it is a division by a small number?

Comment: How many iterations did you expect? and why? Also I recommend that you add some context why the term $\log_2(\frac{b-a}{\varepsilon})$ is important for you.

Comment: @harfe at least 8 iterations due to the formula, I linked where it came from

Comment: If you use $|f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ (which is very wrong), just multiply any function by $10^{-9999999}$ and the solution is reached in one single iteration.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici why using $|f(x)|\leq \varepsilon$ for a given $\varepsilon$ is wrong if we want to bound the error?

Comment: Just what I wrote. Your result must not be sensitive to muliplication or division of the function by any number. What you want is that $|x_n-x_{n-1}| \leq \epsilon$ as explained in comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong error.
In the wikipedia section that you linked, the error concerns the $x$-values
$$
 |x - x_n|
$$
where $x$ is a solution with $f(x)=0$ and $x_n$ is the midpoint in the $n$th iteration.
This is very different from the error of the function values
$$
|f(x_n)|.
$$

A second point that should be mentioned that such a formula usually refers to the maximum number of iterations needed,
not the minimum number of iterations:
If you are lucky, your algorithm can come close to the solution in earlier iterations.

Comment: Wikipedia writes: "$\varepsilon_0$ = initial backet size = $b-a$

Comment: @newhere : You need to use the exact definitions of each symbol. If $ε_k$ is the length of the bracketing interval after $k$ steps, then $ε_0=b-a$ and you want $ε_n=2^{-n}ε_0\le 0.01$. The size of the function values does not occur in this computation.

Comment: @LutzL so in the function $\log_2(\frac{b-a}{\varepsilon})\leq n$ , $\varepsilon$ is a stopping condition on the interval in which the root need to be found?

Comment: Yes. This inequality determines with full control how many steps it takes to reduce the error of $x_n$ to less than $ε/2$,  if $x_n$ is the midpoint of the interval.